# problema com magento

Tags: magento

Ola não sei o que é esse erro que registrou no arquivo de erro:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:63:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away";i:1;s:5412:"#0 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `cms_blo...', Array)
#4 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `cms_blo...', Array)
#5 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(756): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(380): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Resource/Block.php(137): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Cms_Model_Block), 'footer_links', 'identifier')
#8 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Block->load(Object(Mage_Cms_Model_Block), 'footer_links', NULL)
#9 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php(49): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('footer_links')
#10 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Cms_Block_Block->_toHtml()
#11 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('cms_footer_link...', true)
#13 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Footer.php(89): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('cms_footer_link...', true, true)
#14 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/page/html/footer.phtml(35): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer->getChildHtml('cms_footer_link...')
#15 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/dicadete/...')
#16 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#17 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('footer', true)
#21 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/1column.phtml(52): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('footer')
#22 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/dicadete/...')
#23 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#24 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/local/DiegoSouza/CheckoutSimplificado/controllers/IndexController.php(120): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): DiegoSouza_CheckoutSimplificado_IndexController->indexAction()
#30 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#31 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#32 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#33 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#34 /home/dicadete/public_html/lojinhadeteatro.com.br/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#35 {main}";s:3:"url";s:32:"/index.php/checkoutsimplificado/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Packet too large

## MySQL server has gone away

Ocorre quando se envia uma grande quantidade de dados ao servidor MySQL, que por questões operacionais e de performance, limita esta quantidade a 16 MB.

## Server has gone away

## MySQL server has gone away

Este erro ocorre quando você demora para executar uma query após conectar-se ao servidor MySQL, por questões operacionais e de desempenho, o servidor encerra a conexão ociosa automaticamente.
Para resolver este erro, programe seu script para conectar-se ao banco, executar a query e encerrar a conexão.
O tempo de duração de uma conexão ociosa ao servidor é de 15 segundos.

Documentação: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html
http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/MySQL:_Principais_mensagens_de_erro,_suas_causas_e_como_resolver

Comment: As vezes não tem relação com a grande quantidade de dados ou tráfego ou o que quer que seja, simplesmente grandes limitações do próprio servidor !!!!!